# Clustering string based on their length

Tags: string, cluster-analysis

I have a list of strings like {abb, abgt,acctg,tgbs,abs} and so on. The number of strings is defined by user. I need to cluster the strings of similar length together. Which clustering algorithm will be suitable for such case and why?? As far I know K-means need to know number of clusters before hand which I cannot tell as number of string is not predefined.

Comment: you can group by length(str).. no real need for clustering.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your strings. Store them in a map int -> strings, where you use your string length as a key. Done.

This is not clustering. Technically, it is only a simple `GROUP BY` operation. In SQL, you would do `GROUP BY LENGTH(col)`.

k-means is totally the wrong choice here.

Comment: :Thanks a lot for ur suggestion.